# Determine "first user who did x" from aggregate values

Tags: mysql, database

I have a database driven community web site, where users can post entries. Each entry has a date. Now I'd like to know who was the first user who had an entry count of 1000. Is this possible with a SQL query or do I have to do that programatically, counting each post until the limit is reached? Or any other solutions?

Comment: It's probably possible with a correlated subquery, but my brain is mush right now and can't think of how it'd be structured.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
create table posts (
id int not null auto_increment primary key,
user_id int,
post_date date
) engine = myisam;


insert into posts (user_id,post_date)
values 
(1,'2011-03-02'),
(1,'2011-04-10'),
(1,'2011-11-13'),
(2,'2011-03-02'),
(2,'2011-03-02'),
(3,'2011-01-01'),
(3,'2011-01-02'),
(3,'2011-01-03');


select * from (
select posts.*,
   @num := if(@user_id = user_id, @num + 1, 1) as rownum,
   @user_id:=user_id as uid
from posts,(select @user_id := 0, @num := 1) as t
order by user_id asc, post_date asc) 
as tab 
where rownum = 3
order by post_date limit 1
```

This is an example where I find first user who reaches 3 messages. Hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT user_id, time
FROM table
LIMIT 1 OFFSET 999
GROUP BY user_id
ORDER BY time
```

I'm not sure of the placing of ORDER BY at the end there, might need a nested query or something since I'm not using aggregation on time after having done a GROUP BY.

But the part you were probably looking for is the LIMIT X OFFSET Y

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember MySQL syntax, but I think you should do something like this:

First, add to each entry its count (per user, of course). There's probably some MySQL specific way of doing it, but if all else fails, you can do something like

```
SELECT Entry.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Entries E2 WHERE E.id<E2.id AND E.user=E2.user) AS EntryCount
```

With that done, select the first entry with a count of 1000, order by the entry time, and take its user.